# How can I select only ONE element in a list (jetpack compose)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a list of Address and I want that my users select only ONE of them.

```
 LazyColumn {
            items(list.values.size) { index ->
                SelectAddress(
                    info = AddressList,
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    isSelectedAddress = false,
                    onSelectAddress = { /* TODO */ } )
```

In "SelectAddress" there are Text and checkbox like this:

```
@Composable
fun SelectAddress(
    isSelectedAddress: Boolean,
    onSelectAddress: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
        val selectedAddress = remember { mutableStateOf(isSelectedAddress)}

Icon(
            painter = getCheckboxResource(isSelected = selectedAddress.value),
            contentDescription = "Checkbox",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    selectedAddress.value = selectedAddress.value.not()
                    onSelectAddress(selectedAddress.value)
                }
        )
```

Comment: Does this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788366/create-toggle-button-group-in-jetpack-compose-without-radio-buttons/69788600#69788600)